# Python classes/subclasses

Tags: python

I've read over the Python documents regarding classes and subclasses but I've still not seen anything to accomplish what I'm after. Maybe I'm just using the wrong terminology for it. But basically I have created a class and now I want to create a subclass that will have properties so that I can call them similarly to the following:

```
import MyClass

mc = MyClass()

print mc.MySubclass.Property
```

The reason for this is because currently I have several properties in my class and I'd like to make it easier to get them. Like currently I'm just saying mc.category_value where "category" represents a might be like "color" and "value" would be like "red", so it looks like "mc.color_red" or "mc.color_blue" but I'd rather be able to say "mc.color.red". Is this possible?

Comment: That's not what subclasses are. You're looking for composition, not inheritance.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, thanks! I said I might using the wrong terminology... I'll research python composition and see what I can figure out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So inner classes, are possible:

```
class Foo():
    x = 1

    def y():
      print("hello")


    class Bar():
        z  = 2


x = Foo.Bar()
print(x.z)
print(Foo.Bar.z) # added this example to be closer to what you want
```

I use these often with the inner class being private, called something like `_Bar` when I want a struct like object that I don't want to expose. But we also use them when they are like you say, property objects of a factory or something.

Comment: Based on this example I was able to figure it out! Thanks so much!